# SQL - Comparing Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help again. Here's my SQL query :

```
SELECT sp.pro_ID, description, price, sp.sup_ID
  FROM L4_Sup_Pro sp, L4_Products prod
 WHERE prod.our_id = sp.pro_id
   AND (sp.sup_ID = '23' OR sp.sup_ID = '75')
 ORDER BY sp.pro_ID;
```

And this query gives me this result :

[image]

I need to compare the prices of `SUP_ID` column having values `75` and `23`, and display *the cheapest price*. So output will be:

```
PRO_ID  DESCRIPTION       PRICE   SUP_ID
101     Laser Printer     630     23
121     Color Jet Printer 223     23
302     Scanner           399     75
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the tip of the day jarlh! I'm taking a deep dive into SQL after being a casual user for years, was wrestling with the question of what is the preferred norm these days - I still find myself coding (implied) cross join in the FROM clause and joining in the WHERE. Part of me hates moving away from a declarative approach to what feels like a procedural one, take your point about the join being easier to modify with your approach! Can you link to "official" SQL guide commenting on your tip?

Comment: See e.g. [this blog post](https://domm.plix.at/perl/2019_10_small_db_change_and_a_lot_of_problems.html) how a missing join condition screwed up a deployment (it's about Postgres, but that doesn't matter). The root cause was "*I SELECT from three tables, but only provide join conditions for two of them*" - something that would not have happened when using explicit JOIN operators (because a missing join condition produces an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function

```
SELECT pro_ID, description, price, sup_ID
 FROM
 (
  SELECT sp.pro_ID, description, price, sp.sup_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY description ORDER BY price ) as rn
    FROM L4_Sup_Pro sp
    JOIN L4_Products prod
      ON prod.our_id = sp.pro_id
   WHERE sp.sup_ID in (23,75) -- without quotes by considering SUP_ID is a numeric column
  )
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY pro_ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76b21fcfa8848f30065f9d4539aea05d)</kbd>

Comment: it displays the most expensive rather than the cheapest

Comment: excuse me I misread, just remove DESC at the end of the ORDER BY price (default is ascending) @kpAtCh I edited as so.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming columns description, and price stored on L4_Products, you can try below query -

```
SELECT sp.pro_ID, prod.description, prod.price, sp.sup_ID
FROM L4_Sup_Pro sp
JOIN (SELECT our_id, description, MIN(price) price
      FROM L4_Product
      GROUP BY our_id, description) prod ON prod.our_id = sp.pro_id
WHERE sp.sup_ID = '23'
OR sp.sup_ID = '75'
ORDER BY sp.pro_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is aggregation:

```
SELECT sp.pro_ID, description,
       MIN(price), 
       MIN(sp.sup_ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY price) as min_sup_ID
FROM L4_Sup_Pro sp JOIN
     L4_Products prod
     ON prod.our_id = sp.pro_id AND
WHERE sp.sup_ID IN (23, 75)   -- looks like a number so I dropped the quotes
GROUP BY p.pro_ID, description
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a group by with having

```
    SELECT sp.pro_ID, description, 
      min(price) , min(sp.sup_ID) 
      FROM L4_Sup_Pro sp, L4_Products 
        prod
     WHERE prod.our_id = sp.pro_id AND
  (sp.sup_ID = '23' OR sp.sup_ID = '75')
    Group by s.pro_id,description having 
      1= 
     Max(case when price=min(price) 
          then 1 
      else 0 end)
      ORDER BY sp.pro_ID;
```